# Opening a FITS file with Astropy results in FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, astropy, fits

When I use

```
fits_datasweep_gal = fits.open('Macintosh HD/Users/lingxuan/Downloads/datasweep-index-gal.fits')
```

to open a FITS file on Jupyter notebook, it returns:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e5886f60eba2> in <module>
----> 1 fits_datasweep_gal = fits.open('Macintosh HD/Users/lingxuan/Downloads/datasweep-index-gal.fits')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py in fitsopen(name, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache, lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
    149 
    150     return HDUList.fromfile(name, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache,
--> 151                             lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
    152 
    153 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py in fromfile(cls, fileobj, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache, lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
    388         return cls._readfrom(fileobj=fileobj, mode=mode, memmap=memmap,
    389                              save_backup=save_backup, cache=cache,
--> 390                              lazy_load_hdus=lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
    391 
    392     @classmethod

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py in _readfrom(cls, fileobj, data, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache, lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
   1037             if not isinstance(fileobj, _File):
   1038                 # instantiate a FITS file object (ffo)
-> 1039                 fileobj = _File(fileobj, mode=mode, memmap=memmap, cache=cache)
   1040             # The Astropy mode is determined by the _File initializer if the
   1041             # supplied mode was None

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/utils/decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    501                         # one with the name of the new argument to the function
    502                         kwargs[new_name[i]] = value
--> 503             return function(*args, **kwargs)
    504 
    505         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/file.py in __init__(self, fileobj, mode, memmap, overwrite, cache)
    176             self._open_fileobj(fileobj, mode, overwrite)
    177         elif isinstance(fileobj, str):
--> 178             self._open_filename(fileobj, mode, overwrite)
    179         else:
    180             self._open_filelike(fileobj, mode, overwrite)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/file.py in _open_filename(self, filename, mode, overwrite)
    553 
    554         if not self._try_read_compressed(self.name, magic, mode, ext=ext):
--> 555             self._file = fileobj_open(self.name, IO_FITS_MODES[mode])
    556             self.close_on_error = True
    557 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/util.py in fileobj_open(filename, mode)
    386     """
    387 
--> 388     return open(filename, mode, buffering=0)
    389 
    390 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Macintosh HD/Users/lingxuan/Downloads/datasweep-index-gal.fits'
```

What should I do?

Comment: As a general answer to "What should I do?" so that you can have an easier time with problems like this: Although the `astropy.io.fits` code is complicated, you can see in the end of the traceback that the code which raised the `FileNotFoundError` was `open(filename, mode, buffering=0)`.  Forget the `mode` and `buffering` parts for a sec: Most importantly it is calling `open(filename)`.  [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is the Python built-in for opening a file, by default for reading.

Comment: You could try calling `open()` directly on the path you gave and you'll get the same error.  Or even `import os` then check `os.path.exists(filename)` to see if it's an existing path on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Macintosh HD` part from path

```
fits_datasweep_gal = fits.open('/Users/lingxuan/Downloads/datasweep-index-gal.fits')
```